# Display available Bluetooth list in UITableView

Tags: ios, ios5, bluetooth, gamekit, core-bluetooth

I'm new in gaming development. I'm creating a multiplayer game which is connected by Bluetooth. Right now, in my project, I'm using the Game Kit framework to detect available Bluetooth devices. This available Bluetooth list is displaying in `GKPeerPicker` Controller. But now I want to display the available Bluetooth list in a `UITableView`.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the best sample code for  displaying list of  bluetooth devices which are available for us   they he explained clearly
   [Displaying bluetooth devices list](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/43502)

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrievePeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals{
    NSLog(@"This is it!");
// store the list of devices in the NSArray and then go to table view delegates.


}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [peripherals count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray;
    }


    cell.textLabel.text = [peripherals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



    return cell;
}
```

Comment: still i'm not getting available list of bluetooth in uitableview

Comment: peripherals = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil, nil];    
    options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]
 [cbmanager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:peripherals options:options];

Comment: your array is nil then how can it load and r u able to see the table

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [peripherals count];
}

Comment: i also use this <CBCentralManagerDelegate,CBPeripheralDelegate,CBPeripheralManagerDelegate> delegate and all this methods

Comment: the above method is fine but u should have something in ur array

Comment: thats ok but r u able to see the table

Comment: my table is nil..there is no data in my table

Comment: have u implemented the table view delegates and data source in .h and put it to self in .m

Comment: ok keep a breakpoint in the numberofrowsinsection delegate and see if u r getting the count der.Put nslog der and check the count

Comment: should i have to use CBUUID?

Comment: ya u have to.did u not use it.then u won't get the list.

Comment: this is my new code                                             CBUUID *Cbid = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180D"];
    
    options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey];
    
    [cbmanager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:Cbid] options:options];

Comment: i suppose this should work otherwise u need to post ur whole code

Comment: peripherals = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil, nil];
    
    options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey];
    
    [cbmanager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"180D"]] options:nil];
    
    tblBluetoothList = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tblBluetoothList.dataSource = self;
    tblBluetoothList.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:tblBluetoothList];

Comment: - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    return [peripherals count];
    
}

Comment: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        

    }
    
    
    cell.textLabel.text = [peripherals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    
    
    
    return cell;
}

Comment: -(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrievePeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals
{
    NSLog(@"didRetrievePeripherals");
    
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSLog(@"didDiscoverPeripheral");
    
    NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[advertisementData description]]);
}

Comment: - (void)peripheralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBPeripheralManager *)peripheral
{
    
}

Comment: so that is the problem ur count in nil and then u won't get anything in table.please check why it is nil

Comment: I'm not sure about this line, how to pass correct parameters?    peripherals = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil, nil];

Comment: now i m getting this warning in my Project.              CoreBluetooth[WARNING]  is not powered on

Comment: i dont understand why code u r writing,u r making mistake with delegates

Comment: with ur blootooth delegates

Comment: donna why u r not getting the list and becoz of that the table is nil